# Getting a Blob out of an SQLite Database

Tags: android, sqlite, blob

I have a Blob in an SQLite-Database.
When I type:

`Select length(blobblob) FROM Database WHERE id=9387134648;`

I get a size of **20519 bytes** (quite big), but when I fetch the Blob with android:

```
Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("Select ? FROM Database WHERE id=?;",
                new String[]{"blobblob", "9387134648"});

if (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    byte[] bytes = cursor.getBlob(0);
    Log.v("Bloblength", String.valueOf(bytes.length));
}
```

I just get a size of **9 bytes**.

**What** do I do **wrong**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd guess that you're getting the string `"blobblob"` (as an array of bytes) out of your query, those eight characters plus a null terminator would be nine bytes. When you say this:

```
select ? from database where id = ?
```

Both placeholders will be replaced by values from your arguments and the arguments are `String`s so the `?` will be replaced with SQL strings. The result will be a query that is effectively this:

```
select 'blobblob' from database where id = '9387134648'
```

and all that query does is select the SQL string literal `'blobblob'` from your table.

The underlying problem is that you can't use placeholders for SQL identifiers (table names, column names, ...) in a query, placeholders are only for values like strings and numbers. Your code should look more like this:

```
Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("Select blobblob FROM Database WHERE id=?;",
                new String[]{"9387134648"});
```

I'm not much of a Java or Android guy so hopefully I haven't butchered the code.

Comment: Thank you very much! This was the solution. Now everything works :-)